# Load different classes and execute similar function name

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem that I can't resolve.
Let's say we have some classes in a directory named `services`.
Each of theses classes contain a `contructor()` and `send()` method.
We can have differents classes such as `Discord`, `Slack`, `SMS`, etc.
Their goal is just to sent notification through external service.

I think I have to use an interface or an abstract class which contain `contructor()` and `send()` method but how can I instanciate every class and call `send()` in an elegantly way ?

My project structure :

```
services/
  -> discord.js
  -> slack.js
  -> [...]
index.js
```

Regards.

Comment: There is no interface or abstract class in javascript. And there are thousands of ways to instantiate some classes.

Comment: i had the same problem so i created an interface workaround to slove it. you can install it if you like. https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-interface

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. `require` a class, instantiate it and call `send`.

Comment: @estus I need polymorphism or something that looks like polymorphism.

Comment: @Oyabi Javascript is ducktyped. There is no concept of an interface. Just call the method and if it exists it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a kind of manager where you have a single `send()` function that chooses a specific service based on a parameter. Something like this:

**services/index.js**

```
import SlackService from 'slack.js';
import DiscordService from 'discord.js';

export const TYPES = {
  SLACK: 'slack',
  DISCORD: 'discord',
};

export class ServiceManager {
  services;

  constructor() {
    this.services = {
      [TYPES.DISCORD]: new DiscordService(/* discordConfig */),
      [TYPES.SLACK]: new SlackService(/* slackConfig */),
    };
  }

  send(type, data) {
    return this.services[type].send(data);
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import ServiceManager from 'services/index.js';
const serviceManager = new ServiceManager();

serviceManager.send(ServiceManager.TYPES.SLACK, { message: 'Sent to Slack' });
serviceManager.send(ServiceManager.TYPES.DISCORD, { message: 'Sent to Discord' });
```

---

### Dynamically loading services from files

You can use `require-dir` to import all files from a directory and then map over those to create each service. The individual service files have to be written in a defined syntax for the manager to use them. Something like this:

**services/slack.js** (as example for all service files):

```
export const name = 'slack';

export class Service {
  constructor() {
    // Set up connection to slack
  }

  send() {
    // Send something to slack
  }
}
```

**services/index.js**

```
const requireDir = require('require-dir');

export class ServiceManager {
  services;

  constructor() {
    const serviceObjects = requireDir('.');
    this.services = Object.values(serviceObjects).reduce(
      (services, { name, Service }) => {
        services[name] = new Service();
        return services;
      }
    )
  }

  getRegisteredServices() {
    return Object.keys(this.services);
  }

  send(name, data) {
    return this.services[name].send(data);
  }

  sendAll(data) {
    Object.values(this.services).each(service => service.send(data));
  }
}
```

**index.js** (stays pretty much the same)

```
import ServiceManager from 'ServiceManager.js';
const serviceManager = new ServiceManager();

console.log('Registered services are: ', serviceManager.getRegisteredServices());

serviceManager.send('slack', { message: 'Sent to Slack' });
serviceManager.send('discord', { message: 'Sent to Discord' });
```

Comment: Ah, I think that more or less what I want. Thank you very much. However, if I add a new class (SMS for example), I must add code in 3 files : services/sms.js, services/index.js and index.js. Does this sound correct from a software architecture point of view? Can't we instanciate all the classes in services/index.js and and loop through a ServiceManager object in index.js? So the index.js code does not change with each commit.

Comment: I just extended my answer with a slightly different ServiceManager that loads all available services automatically. With this, you only need to add a file `service/sms.js` and the manager will recognize it.
You will still have to add code to `index.js`. That file just serves as an example for anywhere in your application's code where you want to use a specific service.
The `sendAll` function, however, can be added in both solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will study that and implement your solution in my application. Have a nice day and thanks again for your time and your experience.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.